# Jekyll and SinglePaged theme

Tags: css, templates, themes, jekyll

I am trying to get a page up and running on GitHub using Jekyll, and in particular I found the SinglePaged theme (https://github.com/t413/SinglePaged). I followed the instructions to fork and everything, and created two posts:

- 2000-01-01-intro.md
- 2000-01-02-education.md

The contents of the second post are simple:

```
---
title: "education"
bg: turquoise
color: white
---
# Title
test
```

But when I run on a local jekyll server, only this second post is being rendered. When I look at the `index.html` generated in `_site/`, it only contains:

```
<h1 id="title">Title</h1>

<p>test</p>
```

I tested it out by adding more posts, and only the last one (i.e. with the latest date) is being rendered with nothing else. Moreover, the CSS is not being applied on the browser even though all the files are present. Has anyone seen this before?

---

Edit: Look at all the code in my GitHub repository https://github.com/muhammadkhan/muhammadkhan.github.io

Comment: It's possible that there's a problem with the contents of the first post. Do you see any error message when building the site with `jekyll build --trace`? It would be easier to troubleshoot if you could put the Jekyll code with your two posts in a GitHub repository

Comment: @CaioProiete I edited the question pointing to my repo, thank you for the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in [line 10 of your `_config.yml`](https://github.com/muhammadkhan/muhammadkhan.github.io/blob/master/_config.yml#L10). You are setting the permalink to `/` for every single page.

Remove that line, and you'll get your `index.html` the way you expect.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I overlooked that - thanks so much!